# How to disable tunnelling via gradio into k8s container

Tags: kubernetes, security, networking, tunnel, gradio

I am having a jupyter container on k8s and running the below code

```py
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, share=True, inputs="text", outputs="text")

demo.launch(debug=True, share=True)
```

What happens as the result of this is that gradio opens a random port and then tunnels it to a public IP on its own server and gives a link which is https://.gradio.live

This link is public and could be a way for exploitation. Is there any way I can stop this behaviour. I have already specified network policy in k8s with ingress allowed only on the jupyterlab port 8888. But still this public link keeps working.

Please assist on the above.

I am trying to disable the tunneling behaviour into a k8s pod.

Application of network policy to allow ingress only on 8888(jupyterlab) pod was supposed to work but sadly it did not work.